# Why <? extends interface> instead of <? implements interface>

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have the following code:

```
ArrayList<? extends IValues> valuesList
```

`IValues` is an `interface`. 
The list is filled with classes/objects that `implement` the `IValues` interface. 
I do understand the the concept of every object in this list having to fulfill the contract laid down by the interface they implement.
Why doesn't the java language do this like this:

```
ArrayList<? implements IValues> valuesList
```

? This would be much clearer to the user, wouldn't it?

Comment: Do you think it would be clear that `ArrayList<IValues>` matches your proposed constraint?

Comment: Just an arbitrary language design choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntactical choice of which keyword to use is most likely arbitrary in this case. It's just a marker saying that the type argument must be a subtype of `IValues`. This is written with `extends` for inheritance and `implements` for interfaces.

Personally I find it better to use one keyword for both classes and interfaces instead of two different ones. And `extends` is a good choice, especially since you use it in interfaces as well:

```
interface ISpecialValues extends IValues {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

That's how Generics are designed in Java.

Note that the `super` keyword is used here, as well, but it has totally different meaning than *outside Generics*.

Answer (score 1):

There is little going for either `extends` or `implements` because the meanings familiar from pre-Java 5 are inapplicable in either case. The implication of analogy is actually coincidental, forced upon the language designer by the very strong restriction not to introduce new keywords.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the expression is to identify whether a class / interface inherits from `IValues` (or another Class/Interface for that matter). I am guessing that they don't use the keyword `implements` because both keyword `extends` or `implements` would solve the same purpose.

The keywords `extends` and `super` are used to identify whether the class / interface is the child class or base class of some other class respectively.