# Keyword extends with Type Parameter<T> in Generic Java

Tags: java, generics, extends

Consider

```
Gen<T>
```

So, when I write something like this

```
Gen<Integer> someRef = new Gen<>();
Gen<String> someRef = new Gen<>();
```

As per my understanding,

> The Java compiler does not actually create different versions of Gen, 
>       or of any other generic class. Although it’s helpful for me to think in these terms, 
>       it is not what actually happens. Instead, the compiler removes all generic 
>       type information, substituting the necessary casts, to make my code behave 
>       as if a specific version of Gen were created. 
>       Thus, there is really only one version of Gen that actually exists in my program. 
>       The process of removing generic type information is called erasure.

Now consider this one,

```
interface MinMax<T extends Comparable<T>> {
```

> In general, a generic interface is declared in the same way as is a
>   generic class. 
>       In this case, the type parameter is T, and its upper bound is Comparable, which is an 
>       interface defined by java.lang. A class that implements Comparable defines objects 
>       that can be ordered. Thus, requiring an upper bound of Comparable ensures that MinMax 
>       can be used only with objects that are capable of being compared. Notice that 
>       Comparable is also generic. (It was retrofitted for generics by JDK 5.) 
>       It takes a type parameter that specifies the type of the objects 
>       being compared.

Next, MinMax is implemented by MyClass.

Notice the declaration of MyClass, shown here:

```
class MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>> implements MinMax<T> {
```

Here comes my confusion,
When I will write something like this,

```
MyClass<Integer>  ......
```

Type parameter T will be replaced by Integer. or say any other version(depends on type of Objects I will be operating).

I know very well that a class implements an interface. With regard to aforementioned, wouldn't the above case work like this,

```
class MyClass<Integer(or some other version) extends Comparable<Integer>> implements MinMax<Integer> {
```

So, how come a class here is extending an interface,

```
Integer(or some other version) extends Comparable<Integer>
```

I know for sure, my understanding is not correct regarding the above context. Kindly elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that in Generics the keyword `extends` is used in a **different context**.

In Generics, `T extends Something` denotes that `T` will be a sub-class of `Something` *or* will implement `Something` (in the cases of an interface). The type of the bound doesn't really matter (class or interface) - what matters is `T` to be **sub-type** of the provided bound.

More info:

- [Why extends interface instead of implements interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338775/why-extends-interface-instead-of-implements-interface/26338810#26338810)

Comment: A nice link to the answer. Thanks for the same. By the way, other than super and extends keywords, any other such incidence.

Comment: No, these are the only two keywords used in Generics.